# Use custom `Manager` for "default values" creation and fetching

Tags: python, django

I have and `Employee` model and an `EmployeeType` model, with `Employee` having an attribute called `Employee.employee_type` which is of type `EmployeeType`.

Currently on the creation of a client, we run something to create "default" values for the `EmployeeType`.  Right now, that logic is in a method within the module that handles a new client being created... but I was thinking a better place for this would be to be with the `EmployeeType` model.

My question is - would it be appropriate to make a custom `Manager` attribute on the `EmployeeType` that does the creation and/or fetching of these default types? See the following for what I believe I am trying to accomplish:

```py
    class DefaultValueEmployeeTypeManager(models.Manager):
        def get_or_create_default_values(self):
            first_type = self.model.objects.get_or_create(name='First Type')
            second_type = self.model.objects.get_or_create(name='Second Type')
            third_type = self.model.objects.get_or_create(name='Third Type')

            return (first_type, second_type, third_type)

    class Employee(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        defaults = DefaultValueEmployeeTypeManager()


    # Code in another file, handling the setup of a new client
    from models import EmployeeType

    def create_new_client(client):
        # make sure the default values are there
        EmployeeType.defaults.get_or_create_default_values()
```

My question is whether or not this is acceptable/expected behavior for a `Manager` object to handle? Or should this just be some sort of `@classmethod` (or similar) on the `EmployeeType` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but I wouldn't rename the manager to `defaults` because now `objects` is undefined and *all* queries on `EmployeeType` need to use `defaults`, e.g. `EmployeeType.defaults.all()` which doesn't really make sense.

You just want to add an extra method, like described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods).

Just name your manager `objects = EmployeeTypeManager()`, call your manager `EmployeeTypeManager` (it's still the default manager) and your method is just an extra manager method.

Note that `get_or_create` returns a two-tuple of the object and whether or not it was created. So in your code `first_type` is `(<the object>, False)` if the type already exists.

Note also you put this under the `Employee` model, but it's of course an `EmployeeType` model manager.

Comment: fixed to `EmployeeType` instead of `Employee`.